# tensorflow_text is not importing

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text
```

below is the error i am getting ..

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-566f9fbfe6f7> in <module>
      1 import tensorflow_hub as hub
----> 2 import tensorflow_text as text

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_text'
```

laptop config -- os - window 10  cpu- intel i5  gpu- nvidia gtx 1650ti
i have already installed all the required libraries ..   tensorflow version - '2.6.0'

Answer (score 1):

If this package is missing you can install it using [`pip`](https://github.com/tensorflow/text#install-using-pip).

```
pip install -U tensorflow-text==2.6.0
```

Please note the comment:

> When installing TF Text with `pip install`, please note the version of TensorFlow you are running, as you should specify the corresponding version of TF Text. For example, if you're using TF 2.0, install the 2.0 version of TF Text, and if you're using TF 1.15, install the 1.15 version of TF Text.

It is possible, that this package is missing, even if you successfully install `tensorflow`.